# How would a devil get around using its true name on a contract?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore

In the lore, knowing a devil's true name allows you to summon it and grants you power over it.

Devils LOVE contracts, but surely they need to put their full names somewhere on the contract to be binding?

In published lore (for 5e, other versions and novels, etc) how do devils negate this?

Comment: It may be better to ask "How does the devil seal a contract?" instead of the assumption that it's a signature and how they get around it. Although they are pretty much the same thing :P

Comment: @AlanRégis Please don't answer, even partially, in comments. [We try not to do that here.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533)

Comment: Related; In being about the devil's side of such contracts: [What punishment befalls devils who break their contracts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131569/52137)

Comment: You appear to be conflating the metaphysical concept of a true name with the concept of a legal name (sometimes called a true name in legal contexts) or possibly the philosophical concept of a proper name. All three are very different things. True names in the metaphysical sense are a type of sympathetic magic, and are only very tangentially related to the subject’s legal or proper name. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name, as well as the Japanese concept of kotodama, and the ancient Egyptian concept of Ren.

Comment: How legible are signatures in general?
Because there is a reason why on every contract the full name of the signer is printed in regular letters below where they should sign.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It’s impossible to prove a negative, but I’m rather sure there is nothing official that covers this. To that end, here are all the most likely sources across all of D&D to cover something like this, and how they don’t.

Note that numerous sources discuss how fiends all have names other than their “true name,” that they could use for this purpose. As discussed at the end of the answer, real-world contracts wouldn’t require the equivalent of a “true name,” and can even be entered without any name at all. Notably, the recent *Baldur’s Gate: Descent into Avernus* adventure included several forms of infernal bargains, most of which don’t involve anyone signing anything.

### Original D&D and other early editions

Things were not as detailed this far back and a lot of it has been ret-conned since. There may be something about infernal bargains somewhere in the corpus, but finding it may prove beyond my ability.

This far back you also get a whole smorgasbord of different versions of the game, some of them by different authors, not all of them neatly numbered, as TSR sought to flesh out the original rules even as it moved on to the “Advanced” rules. That’s where you get BECMI and the like, the Holmes and Moldvay versions of the game. BECMI in particular was set in Mystara, which is sort of wildly (and intentionally) incompatible with the general cosmology of D&D, so even if it covered things it probably wouldn’t apply to the rest of D&D.

### AD&D

AD&D is, as I understand things, kind of where D&D began to get more cohesive, and that’s where we start to see setting details like this develop more. We still don’t get any information on exactly how infernal bargains are signed on the devil side.

My thanks to @Omortis for this information, since I do not have access to any library of AD&D books.

#### *Monster Manual*, as in, the first one

Devils are discussed, but no details on how devils extract value (e.g. souls) from deals with mortals are offered—instead, it focuses on how a mortal can convince or force a devil to do their bidding.

#### *Fiend Folio*

*Fiend Folio* was like *Monster Manual*, only more evil (but not exclusively so, much less exclusively about fiends). Anyway, no mention of infernal bargains is found here.

#### *Monster Manual II*

Having apparently exhausted their thesaurus with *Fiend Folio*, AD&D goes back to *Monster Manual* a second time. Now, we get the tiniest hint of making deals with devils, but it’s rather scant:

> [Getting a devil to do something for you] also typically requires a contract for the soul of the creature commanding the infernal power to obey

<sup>(Quotation supplied by Omortis, citing *Monster Manual II*)</sup>

and that’s it.

### AD&D 2e

AD&D 2e is where the cosmology of D&D really develops—this is where it got its own product line as the Planescape setting. It also has a **ton** of material. I have spoken with Planescape expert @afroakuma on this, since like the original books and the first edition of AD&D, I don’t have a 2e library.

#### *Faces of Evil: The Fiends*

My understanding is that *Faces of Evil: The Fiends* is the 2e book most likely to cover this. However, I’ve confirmed it does not. It talks about true names and how important it is to keep them secret, and it mentions how important corrupting mortals is to the devils, but it doesn’t get into the details of how infernal bargains are actually made, much less how they’re signed.

#### *A Guide to Hell*

I want to also look through *A Guide to Hell*, if I can only find a copy—so far, I have struck out on that.

### D&D 3e & 3.5e

The third edition, and “v.3.5 revised edition,” of D&D had a number of supplements devoted to devils specifically or fiends more generally. None of them cover this point.

#### *Book of Vile Darkness*

*Book of Vile Darkness* is a weird, “3.25” book published just before the “v.3.5 revised edition” and so it reflects some but not all of the updates from that revision. It also had a prominent sticker on it warning it was for “mature audiences only,” though honestly most of the content is pretty standard early-2000s “edgy teen” schlock.

Anyway, one of the topics covered in the book is “Souls as Power,” which spends a few paragraphs discussing the idea that you can use a soul, once you have it, to power up magic—there are rules for using souls as material components to power-up spells, or using souls instead of one’s own XP when crafting magic items. (3.x had magic items cost XP to create; it was an awkward system.) Aaaand—that’s it. There is a little bit about how one can harvest souls from the Lower Realms, but not about how you corrupt mortals so their souls go there in the first place.

Otherwise, the book contains a bunch of new evil prestige classes (a 3.x term, a class that you could only multiclass into after meeting certain requirements), new evil spells, new evil magic items, and new evil creatures. Scanning the lists of each, none of them touch on dealing for souls. There’s *soul shackles*, a spell that can be cast on a creature already dead to imprison its soul and allow the caster to interrogate it, but that’s as close as we get. The only other vaguely-related option I see is a *souldrinking* weapon, which curses targets and grants the wielder benefits for doing so.

#### *Fiend Folio*

Wizards of the Coast reused the *Fiend Folio* title for another “3.25-ish” book, and again it’s kind of like a more evil *Monster Manual*, though honestly its collection of actual fiends is pretty limited. There are two demons (sentient evil pollution and a vampiric fiend), two devils (a spymaster and a thought-stealer), and two yugoloths (a sergeant in their armies and a spy). None of these descriptions get into signing away one’s soul.

However, towards the back of the book, *Fiend Folio* has a few fiend-specific prestige classes, and most relevantly here, the fiend of corruption prestige class. Fiend of corruption is all about making deals for souls, and gets a number of abilities to empower mortals who sign on the dotted line (ability score empowerment, free wealth via *major creation*, and ultimately, whatever they want via *wish*). The art for the class features a harrowed-looking man with a pen over parchment, as a nude lady-fiend caresses him and wraps him in her wings.

But as to actually signing away one’s soul, all the class offers is

> **Soul Bargain (Su):** At 6th level, a fiend of corruption gains the ability to enter a binding agreement with a mortal, at the cost of the mortal’s soul. The mortal victim must enter into the soul bargain willingly.
>
> Upon the mortal’s death (by any means), her soul is transferred to a gem (prepared as with the *soul bind* spell when the bargain is forged), even if the gem and the mortal are not on the same plane at the time.
>
> The bargain requires 1 hour to complete, and is utterly inviolable once forged. The only way to escape a soul bargain is to recover the gem after the mortal’s death and break it, freeing her soul and allowing her to be restored to life through the normal means.
>
> It is quite common for fiends of corruption, as soon as a soul bargain is complete, to return to their native plane and await the mortal’s death, or at least deposit the gem in a safe place before returning to the Material Plane to hasten the victim’s demise.

<sup>(*Fiend Folio* pg. 204)</sup>

And that’s it, the entirety of the ability. It does reference the spell [*soul bind*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/soulBind.htm), but the rules for that “gem (prepared as with the *soul bind* spell” are merely

> *Focus:* A black sapphire of at least 1,000 gp value for every Hit Die possessed by the creature whose soul is to be bound. If the gem is not valuable enough, it shatters when the binding is attempted. (While creatures have no concept of level or Hit Dice as such, the value of the gem needed to trap an individual can be researched. Remember that this value can change over time as creatures gain more Hit Dice.)

<sup>(*Player’s Handbook* pg. 281)</sup>

So that doesn’t tell us anything about signing anything away.

#### *Fiendish Codex II: Tyrants of the Nine Hells*

Following up *Fiendish Codex I: Hordes of the Abyss*, which was about Chaotic Evil demons who don’t really bother with contracts, *Fiendish Codex II* is all about Lawful Evil devils, very much love contracts. The book discusses the “Pact Primeval” from which Asmodeus and the baatezu get their power, and various other “Faustian pacts” that devils can offer to mortals. The book devotes a few pages to this, but never mentions anything about **how** the pact is signed, on either side.

#### *Heroes of Horror*

*Heroes of Horror* has a much more *Frankenstein*, *Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde* kind of aesthetic, with a bit of Lovecraft thrown in, and so doesn’t focus so much on actual devils. It even refers to fiends as “obvious” and “familiar” sources of evil villains, suggesting that they are thus less suitable for “horror,” and pushes a DM to maybe try out some less-used outsiders like genies and inevitables rather than fiends. And that’s the entirety of their section on “Outsiders as Villains of Horror.”

### D&D 4e

The only 4e book to touch significantly on devils is *The Plane Above*, weirdly enough, since *The Plane Below* is the Elemental Chaos and devils avoid chaos. Anyway, neither book discusses infernal contracts in any fashion.

### D&D 5e

There’s really only one book in 5e to look to here, and it doesn’t provide an answer either.

#### *Baldur’s Gate: Descent into Avernus*

*Descent into Avernus* is primarily an adventure, but it does describe several possible benefits to selling one’s soul. It does not, however, discuss how that gets signed off on by the fiend on the other side, though there is mention of that happening:

> To enter the contract, the devil and the character making the deal sign the scroll in their own blood,

<sup>(*Baldur’s Gate: Descent into Avernus* pg. 215)</sup>

But more importantly, that description applies only to one of six options for the format of an infernal contract:

> **Contract Forms**
>
> | d6 | Contract Form |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Baby dolls |
> | 2 | Damned wretch |
> | 3 | Infernal scroll |
> | 4 | Lemure kiss |
> | 5 | Song of the devil |
> | 6 | Written in stone |

<sup>(*Baldur’s Gate: Descent into Avernus* pg. 214)</sup>

This clearly demonstrates that a deal with a devil **doesn’t necessarily involve a signature at all**. The infernal scroll does, but the others don’t. (Written in stone, for the curious, has each “sign” the stone by pressing their hand into it.)

### Real Life

Per the above, I believe there is no official answer to this question. I would therefore like to address a misunderstanding in it, namely that

> surely [devils] need to put their full names somewhere on the contract to be binding?

This is **untrue**.

In real life, there are **lots of ways to sign contracts**, both in modern times and historically. Devils aren’t the only ones who want to hide their true identity when entering into a contract, you know.

#### Seals

The most likely form of signature for a devil lord isn’t a “signature” at all, but a seal. Seals were—and still are—used to indicate that someone in authority has agreed to something, with greater security and gravitas than a signature can manage. They are harder to forge, much harder to modify after the fact, and also can have the side-benefit of declaring the greatness of whoever’s seal it is to anyone who sees it. This is extremely fitting to devils, who after all tend to style themselves as “dukes” and “archdukes.”

#### “Your mark”

Common among the illiterate, any kind of mark on the page that is reasonably unique can be used in lieu of actual letters. When it really wasn’t that important, a simple “X” has even been used. In the case of an archduke of Hell, you’d expect something fancier than this, but then, especially since they have magic available to assist, perhaps their mark could be very fancy indeed—more like a seal, but without the opportunity to steal it.

#### Any other identifying term

Real-world contracts do not require one’s full legal name—they require enough information to uniquely identify an individual. I live in a city with about a dozen people who share my entire name, for example—my full name alone does not identify me, which is why my mortgage has a bunch of other information about me to make sure we know which Kevin Ryan we’re talking about. When it comes time to enforce a contract, the court is going to read it and if the signatory wants to argue “that’s not me,” they’ll look into how the person is identified and whether or not it suitably establishes that it really was.

Considering that the infernal scroll is signed in the blood of both the devil and the mortal, magic probably can trace that to each of them and it doesn’t matter **what** they write on it. It can be a fake name, nickname, a title, whatever, it doesn’t matter. We know from numerous sources that outsiders have “given names” that they hand out to people for various purposes, to avoid using their “true name,” so they probably mostly use that, but it could be almost anything—with their blood there to identify them, the actual text makes no difference.

#### Shell corporations

This is how real-world individuals and businesses enter into contracts that they don’t want associated with their own names. Devils can do it too.

Comment: I would note that, while a signature can be basically anything...a contract must adequately identify the signing parties--otherwise it is unenforceable. So, yeah, you can draw a smiley face as your signature...but if that contract is to stand up to a legal fight, it needs to actually identify the people who signed it...because "who is smiley face?" Hence why a credit card slip has your *name* printed below the signature line

Comment: @guildsbounty Sure, but there are lots of ways to identify an individual. “The Lord of the Ninth” can really only be one individual, and I certainly wouldn’t want to be any poor schmo caught pretending to that title.

Comment: This is beautifully comprehensive.

Comment: The only information in this context in the AD&D _Monster Manual_ is the concept of amulets in the general description of demons on pg. 16 and talismans in the general description of devils on pg. 20. Any concept of contractual arrangements is left up to the DM.

Comment: @Omortis Interesting; I’m not familiar with that. I tracked down a copy of _Faces of Evil_ on the recommendation of a friend, and I’m looking for _A Guide to Hell_, but I’ll make sure to take a look at that _Monster Manual_ too. When you say the AD&D _Monster Manual_, which one do you mean? (I think there’s at least two? But I could be wrong about that.)

Comment: "I want to also look through A Guide to Hell, if I can only find a copy—so far, I have struck out on that" It's for sale on the Dungeon Master's Guild site for like 5 bucks. https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17390/Guide-to-Hell-2e?filters=0_0_0_0_0_45347_0_0

Comment: Any chance for a TLDR?

Comment: Sorry ran out of edit time - @KRyan - this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_Manual#/media/File:MonsterManual-1stEdAD&D-Cover.jpg - The AD&D _Fiend Folio_ has nothing to say on the topic, however the _Monster Manual II_ says that forcing a devil into service "also typically requires  a contract for the soul of the creature commanding the infernal power to obey", but that's it.

Comment: @Behacad The opening paragraphs should suffice for that purpose. I expanded some on it since your comment to ensure it captures all of the relevant info in the answer.

Comment: @Omortis Thanks very much! I’ve added your notes into the answer; please do let me know if I’ve messed any of it up.

Answer (score 28):

There is not a direct in-lore answer to this that I am able to find. So the best I can do is a partial frame challenge and suggest you look at how this *could be done* by looking at history and even modern legal rules to establish your rules.

Here's [what we know](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-d#Devils)

> Though devils all have common names, every devil above a lemure in station also has a true name that it keeps secret.

So, using what we know, we can look at IRL contract law and historical precedent to determine how they likely do this.

#### Your Signature does not have to be your Name.

To look at modern times, we look to an example in the United States Uniform Commercial Code, [Section 3-402](https://newyork.public.law/laws/n.y._uniform_commercial_code_law_section_3-401)

> A signature may be made [...] by the use of any name, including a trade or assumed name, or by a word, mark, or symbol executed or adopted by a person with present intention to authenticate a writing.

As you can see from the above, you don't have to use your 'legal name' to sign a contract. It just has to be a mark that identifies you. In modern times, this rule mostly comes up with people signing nicknames, or shortenings of their full name. For example, if your name is "Isaac Joshua" but you go by 'Josh' and sign that name to a contract--it's still legally binding because that is a name that identifies you.

In fact, there are people that sign credit card slips with a *smiley face,* but it's still legally binding because they "made their mark" on the slip.

This is based in a very long-running historical precedent...the Uniform Commercial Code is simply a modern manifestation of it. But we can go even further--throughout history there are all kinds of different ways that documents have been signed.

- Fingerprint--used frequently in ancient Babylon, China, and Persia. Used today in India, and the last time it came up in court in the US (2013), a fingerprint was deemed a legally binding signature.
- A stylized mark or just an 'X'--generally used by individuals who were not literate. (see below for extra details on this)
- Seals--the 'Wax Seals' that you see turn up in medieval movies and shows? Those were a form of signature. A complex sigil that uniquely identified a person (or at least a noble family), and would be affixed to a document to verify who it came from.

So, with this as an established precedent, your Devil has a ton of options--but the core of them is this: a signature doesn't have to be your True Name.

#### Contracts and Identification

Ultimately, this is more the point where you are likely to run into an issue with 'True Names' coming up. While a signature can be practically any mark, a contract intended to hold up in a legal battle must accurately identify the individuals who are signing it

Yes, you can sign things with an X--but that doesn't effectively identify you for enforcement of the contract. The historical standard in this particular case was that if someone was not able to sign their name, there had to be a witness present who could add that individual's name as a notation. In modern times, this is generally solved by having your name printed somewhere on it separate from where you sign (such as printed below the line on a credit card signature slip)

But again, here is the thing: you don't have to use your legal name. The rule for identification in contracts is that the contract must "Adequately Identify the parties." In other words, if you put the contract in front of a judge, they can figure out who the people who signed it are.

It is preferable, in this case, to use legal names...because that is a clear way to Adequately Identify you. However, it is very common for people to use their preferred name in contracts because *that's how people know them.*

So, as long as the contract can accurately identify the Devil that is offering it, it doesn't need to include their True Name. As pointed out in the lore above...their 'Common Name' is likely what they will use, simply because that's the name that everyone knows them by.

#### Fluff

To go a bit out of factual and into "How I do things..."

I once had the occasion to detail this for my players, and they found it sufficiently legalistic and bureaucratic to satisfy them. Consider first that Devils are all part of a massive system designed to pull people into contracts.

If they need a way to accurately identify themselves without giving mortals their True Names, then they will create one. And it will be extremely rigorous, because they don't want some mortal squirreling their way out of a deal because the contract failed to identify the signing parties correctly.

So, the way I explained this to my players was as such. The contract includes the following information about the Devil you signed with...

- Their Common Name
- Their rank in the infernal hierarchy
- A uniquely identifying code that is their ID code in the Infernal Hierarchy
- The Common Name of their direct superior
- The ID code of their direct superior
- A uniquely drawn sigil that serves as that fiend's signature--marked in their blood

And if you trace things along up the chain of command far enough...Asmodeus knows the True Name of every Devil, and also knows their unique ID.

Thus, a Devil's True Name is protected, but the bureaucracy of the Nine Hells ensures that the Devil is adequately identified in the contract nonetheless.

Comment: Bravo on modeling an evil bureaucracy via RL evil bureaucracy.  Well done, +1.

Answer (score 14):

#### A creature's secret true name is not their common name.

In short, there's no rule that says a devil has to use their "true name" when signing a contract with a mortal. The name devils go by is merely their common name, and their true name is always kept secret.

*Dragon Magazine* #68 (Dec 1982), p.56, *From the Sorceror's Scroll*, introduces a spell called *truename*, which asserts that a creature's "true name" is not merely the name by which they are known, but rather a special, secret name.

*Dragon Magazine* #91 (Nov 1984), *Nine Hells revisited*, p.19, concurs with this:

> Again, it should be noted that **the names by which all devils are commonly known are *not* truenames**; use of such common names will often *summon* the being concerned from the hells, but the devil will not be under the control of the speaker unless other magical preparations hae been made.

This lore continues throughout editions of D&D, including D&D 3e's *Book of Exalted Deeds* and *Tome of Magic*. According to these sources, a creature's truename is not what they call themselves, but what the multiverse calls them. It is a unique identifier, like a cosmic social security number for that being. It is entirely possible to not know your own truename. *Dragon* #317, *Truenames and Fetishes*, describes a truename as:

> [...] a secret magic name that affords you power [...] a unique word of power intrinisically linked to your being.

*Dragon* #346, *The Power of Truenames*, describes it thusly:

> Every creature in existence, from the lowliest peasant to the mightiest dragon, has a truename, a single word that describes it in the language of creation.

Now, the main lore on devils signing contracts with mortals appears in *Fiendish Codex II: Tyrants of the Nine Hells*, p.22-25. It says nothing about requiring the devil to sign the contract using their true names. The terms of the contract must be described in detail, and a copy may be given to the mortal if they remember to ask for one. The mortal may also be forbidden from disclosing the contents of the contract.

However, there's no actual rule which says the mortal must disclose their truename. If a mortal signs a contract with Dispater, there's no rule or lore which says Dispater cannot simply sign "Dispater". And Dispater is only his common name, but his true name; his true name is so secret that it has never appeared in any D&D book. Otherwise, any spellcaster could bind him just by calling on "Dispater".

(In fact, *Fiendish Codex II* only says that the mortal must sign the contract, and in their own blood. It doesn't necessarily say that the devil has to sign or put their name to the contract at all. This might be inferred, however, by how contracts between two parties work in the modern day.)

D&D 5e's *Monster Manual* asserts that devils have a common name and a true name, which they keep secret. Since signing a contract is a common activity for devils, it should probably be inferred that they do not reveal their true name to just anyone, even when they sign a contract.

The AD&D 2e *Planescape* sourcebook *Planes of Law* says in *A Player's Guide to Law*, p.20, that the devils are experts at writing contracts and finding loopholes, and have been making deals since before human civilization arose. This suggests to me that if there's any way to avoid revealing one's true name, it's known to them.

Comment: Is there any lore at all about signing contracts?

Comment: _Fiendish Codex II_, p.22-25, describes contracts signed between devils and mortals, and their arbitration by Infernal judges. I've mentioned the relevant part in my answer. The key part is that there's no rule defining how devils sign their name, if at all. Canonically, they want to take credit for capturing the mortal's soul, but since most other devils don't know their truename, it is unlikely that they would need to use their truename to identify themself to their superiors.

Comment: Cool, so really the truth here is that there is no lore on how contracts are sealed. They just 'are'.

Comment: @NautArch Right. Essentially, the strongest argument is that devils keep their true name secret, which means they can't possibly give it away to every random human who sells their soul.

Comment: I just think that the assumption of a signature is a rough assumption - and your answer goes into the fact that they never say a sig is required.

Comment: To your point in the second to last paragraph, I can easily see that the devil just ended up in possession of a signed contract (like Ursula having the contract with Arial's signature).  The devil *having* the contract is what keeps it binding, and the devil could swap possession of the contract with other devils or demons, which would pass the signer's obligation to the contract's new owner.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson Devils are described as highly bureaucratic, so I can totally see them developing some kind of stock market style system trading subprime mortgages and futures in existing soul contracts.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is a misunderstanding of what a 'true name' is. A true name isn't a *legal* name required for all official documentation; it's something mystical and intensely personal. It's the name on your soul, not the name on your birth certificate.

I am, in part, drawing this understanding from real life literary sources such as Egyptian myth (wherein Isis gains power over Ra by learning his true name) and Ursula K. LeGuin's *Earthsea* books (possibly the the most famous modern literary use of true naming); but this also falls in line with the description of Truename magic as given in the 3rd Edition book *The Tome of Magic* (which of course may not be particularly useful in understanding 5th edition).

Still, the Monster Manual pretty well implies the answer to this question in the sidebar about Devils' true names:

> Though devils all have common names, every devil above a lemure in station also has a true name that it keeps secret.

Since the book directly says they keep their true names secret, clearly they don't write them down on all their fiendish contracts. We can therefore infer that they use their common use-names for those purposes. If you sign a contract with the devil Mephistopheles, that's what it will say on the contract, but that's his common name, the one that's safe to share with others.

As a point of interest, the same thing is true of contracts in our world. You don't need to sign with your full legal name; you only need to sign with something that is clearly identifiable as you. For example, if your name was James Dean Walker, but you go by JD and sign a document "JD Walker", that's still a legally enforceable document. You could even sign it as Dean Walker or Bubba Walker, as long as that's your preferred form of address. It's *better* to use your actual legal name, but courts around the world have upheld that as long as it's clearly you and that you clearly intended to sign the agreement, it's enforceable. (As a counter-example, if you "signed" a contract as "I already told you I wouldn't agree to this, idiot", you clearly didn't sign with the intent of completing the contract, and most courts would hold the document invalid.)

Comment: Is that what they do, though? Can you support that?

Comment: The book says they keep the name secret.  A name you sign on all your fiendish contracts isn't a secret. QED.

Comment: Your support is in regarding modern legal documents, not infernal ones. Are you certain that they are the same? If so please support

Comment: I updated my post, but to be clear, I'm not using modern law as support for D&D. I'm using a logical extrapolation from what the text says.

Comment: +1 for citing LeGuin's Earthsea novels.  The quotes in Quadratic Wizard's answer, especially "*single word that describes it in the language of creation.*" sound exactly like how true names work in Earthsea, IIRC, so the mechanics as well as the overall concept are very similar.

Answer (score -2):

The lore is weak and incomplete on the point you are asking, so different authors/creators will likely use whatever is more convenient for them, or continue to gloss over exactly what is happening.

I can't think of any 5th examples, but most of the times when a contract is entered, it's not so much the act of signing their name, but using their blood. Their blood is the key to the magical contract. It seems wasteful to me for a contract to have to somehow check if the person signing it is using their true/full name. Instead, it can just use the essence of the individual instead. So when Glarb the blob signs, he might use his normal reference of the blobness but his essence still seals the contract.

Comment: Can you support this with examples from other editions or lore?

Comment: @NautArch Does Way of the wicked signing in your own blood work?

Comment: What is "way of the wicked?"

Comment: Its an adventure path, unsure if it was official or not